In SageMath, how to use GF() on a very large finite field which is several thousands bits long?
As far I understand it correctly, GF(Integer) is used to declare a finite field which can for example be used for declaring an elliptic curve (this is what I want to do).
But why using a very large composite number (2 or 3 thousands bits long) like :
GF(12092909088188237225393433017559174875623137613219078327682045681675023350320878590139619158941453632724570634378148379186020109423506557278061404249513976103803771139954000579995199902828634263992330574392218791796266323480026479977659504287064359209036331389750395884727865805793574046154686347934603866375769645860851559671200189106819576945533990794197558448169154800495832790107673176422796675256499746815795625450299074794144048526198146639914021389804755241528331708078456200260597013666698340612446162656471808349941941036242500801205678881620332591272087635015318077794473705628671572713897714140224506269671672327501746902155512482220944778556374239955378577691861316356789180373125486706142640931817968722234080019888921817141837856053156323850750365255047978587780912486395587404967932864588640269696396456375831408999624015664858331115319294937654521467886227817728683577618500683880562054279134724944161)

seems to take too much time to be feasible ? What’s the workaround to declare a dummy elliptic curve using a finite‑field without using GF() ?
The underlying operation I want to do is to E_extend() a point to the new curve which I thus need to declare using the EllipticCurve() constructor where the finite field become the modulus. I don’t know the formula nor any language library that allows to do this outside SageMath.

Need a workaround for https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/38376 or how to do the same thing in an other language.

GF(p^k) and Z//(p^k) are different animals. Which one do you want?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I want to declare a weak elliptic curve defined over the binary field specified in my question. I don’t care how it’s being done.

This is an unfortunate consequence of the default constructor for finite fields. Because your field is a degree 12 extension of a prime field with large characteristic, Sage spends an insane amount of time to look for an irreducible polynomial of degree 12 with special properties (called a "pseudo-Conway polynomial" in Sage).
The workaround is to choose the modulus yourself, e.g., like this:
n = 12092909088188237225393433017559174875623137613219078327682045681675023350320878590139619158941453632724570634378148379186020109423506557278061404249513976103803771139954000579995199902828634263992330574392218791796266323480026479977659504287064359209036331389750395884727865805793574046154686347934603866375769645860851559671200189106819576945533990794197558448169154800495832790107673176422796675256499746815795625450299074794144048526198146639914021389804755241528331708078456200260597013666698340612446162656471808349941941036242500801205678881620332591272087635015318077794473705628671572713897714140224506269671672327501746902155512482220944778556374239955378577691861316356789180373125486706142640931817968722234080019888921817141837856053156323850750365255047978587780912486395587404967932864588640269696396456375831408999624015664858331115319294937654521467886227817728683577618500683880562054279134724944161
k = GF(n.prime_divisors()[0])
m = k['z'].irreducible_element(12)
K.<z> = k.extension(m)


The point of my question is I need to declare an Elliptic curve where the GF() is itself the curve’s modulus. This doesn’t work for declaring an Elliptic curve using the EllipticCurve() constructor.

Ok, so you want a curve with a given number of points, as used in zero-knowledge proof systems? The answer is you can't. There is no simple algorithm to do that in general. There are a few ad hoc techniques used in cryptography to generate special examples, but to the best of my knowledge Sage (nor any other computer algebra system) does not implement any of them.
Your best shot is to take curves from the literature, or implement those techniques yourself. But this is a very different question from what you originally asked, which is why GF(...) is slow, so you should open a new question.

I want to declare the type of weak curve I want to use for basic curve arthmetic exercising. I don t need building conway pseudo polynomials to do that. So I need a work around for the GF() finite field. This is a syntax question.

I don't understand you. I told you how to construct the field, now you can easily construct a curve with that field as base field using EllipticCurve. If this does not satisfy you, show your code.

Your code allows to to define elliptic curves over z elements of the order I want instead of doing it directly on the order. When you perform a scalar multiplication, the result x and y is in the form of result×z¹²+result×z¹¹+result×z¹⁰+result×z⁹+result×z⁸+result×z⁷+result×z⁶+result×z⁵+result×z⁴+result×z³+result×z²+result×z instead of giving the whole result directly (where the size of each individual members have the size of the original prime field).

I'm sorry, I still don't understand you. Your use of mathematical terms is out of place and it is very difficult to understand what you want:

First, what do you mean by "order"?

Sorry, order is a synonym of ring/finite field in my language. What I’m meaning is the x and y coordinate are supposed to consist each one of a single integer. But you declare the finite field over z instead of doing it directly in a different way than I did, hence the reason I’m getting numbers written as a z exponent.

If you're only interested in the points over the base field (in your case, GF(21888242871839275222246405745257275088696311157297823662689037894645226208583), then why don't you define the curve over the base field?

I need the larger field unfactorized.

So, if I understand you correctly, you expect elements of GF(p^12) to be represented by integers, instead of polynomials. I think you may be severely confused on the difference between GF(p^12) and Zmod(p^12).

The former is the Galois field with p^12 elements, i.e. the quotient of GF(p)['x'] by an irreducible polynomial.
The latter is the ring of integers modulo p^12. It is not a field (for example, p has no multiplicative inverse), and it doesn't make much of a sense defining an elliptic curve over it, however Sage has some limited support for curves over rings and you can just type EllipticCurve(Zmod(p^12), [a, b]).

Thank you for zmod. Now outside this topic. How is solving the discrete logarithm between field elements is different from Integers on a ring?

First, the discrete log of an element is not always well defined in a ring (for the same reason that 0 has no discrete log). Second, you may want to learn about the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm, which in particular implies that discrete log in Zmod(p^12) is not more difficult than discrete log in Zmod(p).

But you were probably interested in the discrete log problem for a curve defined over Zmod(p^e). The theory is more complex, but in many cases the conclusion is the same: it is not more difficult than the discrete log for the same curve over Zmod(p). See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.15543
